# Execute an event only if it wasn't fired for a given amount of time in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, settimeout

I have a WPF app with a MouseWheel event. The operations in this event is quite heavy. So, I would like to execute this event only when the user has stopped scrolling (i.e.: if he doesn't scroll for a given amount of time).

In JS, this is quite easy, I can just put the `setTimout` in a var and then do a `clearTimeout` on that var if another scroll happened before the execution of that `setTimeout` (this is quite useful for auto-completion for instance).

How can I achieve that in `c#`?

Comment: Stop and restart a DispatcherTimer whenever the event occurs. Do the final event action on the timer's Tick handler.

Comment: The search term to use for this is "Debounce".  For example, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jul/02/debouncing-and-throttling-dispatcher-events or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay?view=net-5.0

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with the 'multithreading' tag? Do you want to execute the heavy operations on a different thread than the UI thread?

Comment: @Clemens, that's perfect, thanks, can you add your comment as a response, so I can accept it?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, no, just because timer related operations are usualy bound to a new thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` (for WPF) and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<MouseWheelEventArgs>> query =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<MouseWheelEventHandler, MouseWheelEventArgs>(
            h => ui.MouseWheel += h, h => ui.MouseWheel -= h)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250.0))
        .ObserveOnDispatcher();

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            /* run expensive code */
        });
```

The docs say this about `Throttle`:

> Ignores the values from an observable sequence which are followed by another value before due time with the specified source and dueTime.

Answer (score -2):

Something like the following might suit your needs

```
public class perRxTickBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly Subject<T> _innerSubject = new Subject<T>();

    public perRxTickBuffer(TimeSpan? interval = null)
    {
        if (interval == null)
        {
            interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }

        Output = _innerSubject.Sample(interval.Value);
    }

    public void Tick(T item)
    {
        _innerSubject.OnNext(item);
    }

    public IObservable<T> Output { get; }
}
```

Create an instance where T is the event args type for your event.

Set an appropriate timespan value - perhaps 1/4 second for your case.

Just call `Tick()` from you event handler, and then subscribe to the `Output` observable for a regulated flow of 'events'.

Comment: Doesn't this require to add a dependency to the [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) package?

Comment: I don't understand... where do I put the code that is supposed to be executed when there is not more scroll?